# Display unknown new line in HTML

Tags: html, html-table

I'm using this simple HTML code

```
<html>

    <head>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;
         maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;' />
        <meta name='apple-mobile-web-app-capable' content='yes' />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div align='center'>
            <img src='data:image/png;base64,Base64_code' />
        </div>
        <br/>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <br/>April 2, 2013
                    <br/>xxxxxxx
                    <br/>
                    <br/>2xxxxx xxxxxxx
                    <br/>xxxxxxxx
                    <br/>
                    <br/>Hello xxxx,
                    <br/>
                </td>
                <br/>
                <td>
                    <br/>
                    <img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,Base64_code' />
                    <br/>
                </td>
                <br/>
            </tr>
            <br/>
            <tr>
                <br/>
                <td colspan='2' align='center'>
                    <br/>
                     <h2><font color='blue'>xxxxxxxxxxx</font></h2>

                    <br/>
                </td>
                <br/>
            </tr>
            <br/>
            <tr>
                <br/>
                <td>
                    <br/>xxxxxxxxxxxx
                    <br/>
                    <br/>xxxxx xxxxx
                    <br/>
                    <br/>xxxxxxx
                    <br/>
                    <br/>xxxxxxxx
                    <br/>
                    <br/>xxxxxx
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>xxxx
                    <br/>xxxx
                    <br/>xxxxxx
                    <br/>
                </td>
                <br/>
                <td>
                    <br/>
                    <img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/
               +691//2Q==' />
                    <br/>
                </td>
                <br/>
            </tr>
            <br/>
        </table>
    </body>

</html>
```

But when display, it have some unknown new line:

I use Inspect Element of Chrome and see something like that

[image]

I don't know the reason! How can I fix it?

Comment: Formatting your code properly might help you see where all those came from (try http://ctrlq.org/beautifier/).

Comment: @AlfredXing: no javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [content model of tr elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tr-element) is "Zero or more td or th elements".

Since a br element is not allowed there, your browser is attempting to recover from the error by moving it to before the table.

To solve the problem, [write valid HTML](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: CAn i make new  line in <td>?

Comment: Yes. br elements are allowed as children of td elements. (It rarely makes much sense to use them there though).

Answer (score 1):

Remove all `<br/>` from your `<tr>` will solve your issue.

Comment: Putting a br element inside a td element won't cause the issue described.